# Pass file to GHCi and receive output on command line?

Tags: command-line, haskell, ghci

In Python one can say this:

```
python script.py
```

from the command line and receive `script.py`'s output inlined. Is it possible to do this with Haskell's GHCi? Basically I'm wondering if there's a way to run a Haskell program from the command line without compiling and without the user entering the interpreter.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`runghc` is what you're looking for. From its manpage:

> `runghc` is  considered  a  non-interactive interpreter and part of The Glasgow
>   Haskell Compiler. `runghc` is a compiler that automatically runs its results at
>   the end.

Edit: Ubuntu provides a symlink called `runhaskell`, but it might not be standard.

Comment: runhaskell is standard, but may be served by either hugs or GHC.